# SQL How to Select * into temp table output from stored procedure with paramaters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, parameter-passing

I've looked through many questions before asking the following:
I don't have permissions to edit this Stored Procedure, only to run it and define the parameters. I need to aggregate the data from the output. For that, I am trying to store the output of the Stored Proc into a Temp table first. This is what I am trying to do, but obviously SQL doesn't recognize this:

`SELECT *
INTO #temp1
FROM
    (

        EXEC [dbo].[LockedStoredProc]
         @START = '12/01/2016'

        ,@END = '12/01/2018'
        ,@PLAN_TYPE = 'all'

        GO
    )`

Is there any way to get this to work the way I am trying to?
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table

Comment: The second answer is a cleaner solution. I wouldn’t skip over it.

Comment: Thanks, but I have 3 parameters I'm trying to input values for. None of the answers address this situation.